# Continuous scroll for ePub reader in PWA

Tags: epub, apps

Is anyone aware of limitations that would prevent an ePub reader within a PWA built with Typescript/Javascript in an Ionic/Angular framework from having continuous/infinite scroll?

Comment: ```
this.rendition = this.book.renderTo("book",{ flow: "continuous-scrolled", });
```
works for each section except the first page. After calling `this.rendition.next()` from the first page, scrolling works correctly. But I don't know how to fix it for all sections. I want all sections to scroll.